# Widget Disappearing in IE

Tags: widgets, widget-text

Im debugging my site in IE, and my widget area is disappearing.

http://pcdconsultancy.co.uk/

Any ideas? I have no transparency or anything on this.

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: I can see the widgets in IE.

Comment: could it be my cache you think?

Comment: I see the sidebar widgets, but some stuff is missing from your footer, and it looks like you have some CSS3 in your slider that isn't working in IE.

Comment: yea, i think thats to do with the opacity or transparency :) trying to work round the issues now... im not sure why its missing which is really odd!